# Automating output from Access to Word, is it possible?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-word, ms-access-2013

I have several reports in Access that I wanted to merge into one Word document, and that the Word document updated against access when opened, but this proved to be almost impossible. (Atleast at my level)

I tried to use a macro to export to Excel, and then link that into Word. But for some reason embedded object can not be longer then one page (!), so I am back at ground zero...

I have tried reading up on different sources, but right now I just dont know in what direction to go..

So the question is: **What options do I have in exporting MS Access reports and queries to Word?**

I am aiming at as much automation as possible, so that the Word report is the same, but I can only update the lists and statistics automatically.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Why do you want to export to Word? Will you be adding commentary or do you just want it all compiled in one document?

Comment: Both. I want to have the formats that Word offer, so that I can comment on it, and I want it to be easy to update from month to month. (One report for every month). I am doing a report on human trafficking, and I want the report to be an eye catcher. The black on white reports from Access alone will just drown in the pile.

Comment: You have access to all the same colours and fonts in MS Access report writer that you do in Word, but it certainly doesn't have any commenting ability. Let me do some research.

Comment: Here's a bit of Access code that you can use: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1662850-create-word-document-access.html. I guess you would need to create bookmarks in the document first called `empTitle`. Do some research on MS Word bookmarks - that's the key. If you try that code and have issues, post back.

Comment: Not directly for use from Access itself but generic for any SQL data source this question was already asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972024/how-to-retrieve-data-from-sql-database-in-word-2010, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys, at least I got a place to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a newbie workaround to my question, it might not be suited to all situations, but I get it to work.

1. I export an .rtf from Access.
2. I open Word, and go to the menu "View", and then select "Outline".
3. Press "Show document".
4. You now get to insert subdocuments by using the "Insert" button.

The report wont update automatically, but it makes it somewhat less of a hassle to update the report manually..